# What errata or house rules help balance occasionally-broken scenarios?

Tags: house-rules, betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Many of the haunt scenarios can be exceptionally unbalanced depending on precisely where all the players are standing (particularly the revealer and/or traitor) when the haunt is revealed. When my group was playing this game on a regular basis we simply opted to never play certain haunts (that list has since been lost). Are there any better solutions? Perhaps a large list of errata or special cases that fix some or all of these sorts of problems?

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty much how the game is designed. It is a catch-22; sure, it's completely "random" and new every time, but that also means it's impossible to predict and balance accordingly.

Something me and my friends do when these "broken" haunts happen is tweak the conditions around a bit. An example would be haunts that require exorcisms: If we are all high sanity/knowledge characters, we may add 1 or 2 to the number of successes needed, or subtract them if we are dumb/insane. It helps to create an even playing field at the start of the haunt, but still leaves opportunity for game-changers as the game goes on.

Comment: Plenty of haunts have conditions on arrangement to make sure the traitor isn't within N tiles of their goal, or immediately adjacent to another player, etc. What I'm looking for are addendums like that to fix other randomly-unbalanced haunts.

Comment: could you give me an example of one so i have an idea of what you mean?